# How does base64 encoding work in Tiled map editor

Tags: dictionary, encoding, base64, editor, tiled

I am using the Tiled map editor for my game that I program in C++ and after I implemented loading methods for my levels using the raw XML .tmx file (no base64 and no zlib compression) I wanted to now do it with base64.

Here comes my problem/question:
How does the Tiled map editor converts a data structure like this:

```
<tile gid="25"/>
<tile gid="25"/>
<tile gid="25"/>
<tile gid="25"/>
<tile gid="25"/>
```

to a base64 encoded string like this:

```
GQAAABkAAAAZAAAAGQAAABkAAAA=
```

?

I think I need to understand that in order to implement the laoding methods for this. I am wondering how to know where the ID of another tile starts and why the encoded string does not match the one I get when I copy my IDs over to https://www.base64encode.org/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base64 encoded version of the data is an array of unsigned 32-bit integers in little-endian byte order, each representing a "gid" of a tile. You can find more information about how to process this data on the [TMX Map Format](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/#data) page.